# Picture book about an animal traveling through an abandoned house?

Tags: identification-request

This book was read to me when I was a kid, somewhere between 2003 and 2005. I unfortunately have no idea about the author or when it was released, and can't really recall the cover apart from it being pretty dark in color. It centered an animal traveling through an abandoned house.

Key details:

- The book was relatively wide with a hard cover, I believe. It didn't have a whole lot of pages. It had a realistic, painterly art style with darker pallets.
- I can't remember the species of the animal, but I think it could have either been an owl, fox, raccoon, or mouse. I could be wrong on this, though.
- The story was narrated, and the animal/animals did not speak at all.
- A looming pair of eyes appeared throughout the book. They looked like cat or owl eyes.
- The scenery was very detailed, and the abandoned house was fairly fancy. I particularly remember a large bedroom with white, possibly tattered curtains.

This is all I can remember at the moment. I've been trying to find this book on and off for a long time, with no luck.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Could you please add which language this was in?

Comment: @Tsundoku Oh yeah, it was in English!